# JSON Schema - Enum or object

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to write a schema to validate the following.

An object `Foo` can have any amount of properties that must be either an enum or another instance of `Foo`.

e.g. assuming that the enum values are either A or B, a valid object might look like.

```
{
  "test": "A",
  "test1": "B",
  "test2": {
    "test4": "A",
    "test5": {
      "test6": "B"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

A nicer and shorter is schema with self reference, you can try [online](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)

`anyOf` is better than `oneOf`, because `oneOf` needs to validate against all items to ensure that there is only one pass, but `anyOf` can stop after first pass skipping other items.

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "enum": ["A", "B"]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "$ref": "#"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

`anyOf` at root level required to workaround JSON Schema limitation that `$ref` make all sibling keywords ignored.

Checked with [ajv cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv-cli)

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    {"$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"}
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "Foo": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "enum": ["A", "B"]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```